# Amazon S3 folder manipulation with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have one instance in Amazon EC2. It is a Photobook. User can signup and upload images and they can create a photobook. S for that we want S3 storage. I searched a lot for a good PHP class to manipulate these folders, images and html files.

Now I have no idea how we can create folder, delete folder and search for a folder.

Can anyone help  find a solution for these folder/image manipulation requirements like create , search, delete?

Answer (score 4):

The official PHP SDK?

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/

http://aws.amazon.com/php/

Answer (score 4):

Good question. I was trying to do it now and didn't found the answer in any documentation.

So I discovered that you just need to send the entire path in $keyname parameter:

```
folder/my_file_name.jpg
```

The S3 service can recognize and creates automatically the folders.

I think as me, you were looking for a method create_folder-like.

Easy and tricky.